# What is the limiting behavior of a Taylor series?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, taylor-expansion

Given a sequence $a_n$, what can be said about the limiting behavior of $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} z^n$ as $z \rightarrow \pm\infty$? This seems like a pretty natural question to ask, so can anyone point me to some resources discussing it?

I've wondered about this for a long time, but for my particular application, I have a sequence $a_n = c + O(b^n)$ for some $b\in(0,1)$, and I'm wondering if anything can be determined about the the behavior of $f(z)$ as $z$ goes to $-\infty$.

EDIT: as I can see from the comment section knowing the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$ is not enough to know what happens to $f$ as $z\rightarrow-\infty$. Is there any way by looking at $a_n$ to determine the asymptotic behavior of $f$ or is is a lost cause?

Comment: Usually the question is about the radius of convergence, which is to say $\left ( \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left ( \frac{a_n}{n!} \right )^{1/n} \right )^{-1}$ (where we understand $0^{-1}=+\infty$). If this is $+\infty$ then you can ask about the limiting behavior *per se*.

Comment: For my example, the function is known to have infinite radius of convergence. I'm wondering if it's possible to predict what it will do when the magnitude of $z$ gets large

Comment: Well, as $z \to +\infty$ in your case everything is dominated by $ce^z$. As $z \to -\infty$ you need to "open up" that $O(b^n)$ to see what exactly it is in order to know what's really going on. (For example, if it is *actually* $b^n$, then that term would just be $e^{bz}$ whose behavior you understand very well).

Comment: Do you know of any techniques for doing that, or any resources I can look at for help?

Comment: Depends on what the $O(b^n)$ term is. If you really only know it is $O(b^n)$ then there's nothing you can do, that is too general. (Consider for instance that the $O(b^n)$ term could be a completely arbitrary polynomial.)

Comment: OK. Then how can I analyze $a_n$ so that I can get an idea of the behavior of this function? I can break it down more but there doesn't seem to be a finite number of break-downs that'll tell me anything. That's why I'm wondering if there's some other approach, or are there any books/articles I can look at for more info

Comment: At the very least you need some kind of a $\Theta$ estimate for $a_n-c$, not just a $O$ estimate.

Comment: But would that really help though? E.g. if I knew it was $c + c' b^n +O(something < b^n)$ I wouldn't really be getting anywhere would I?

Comment: I see your point; indeed it isn't enough to even have all the information about $n \to \infty$ in general. That term could be $O(0)$ and you still would not know the asymptotics of the whole function.

Comment: Hey @DarkMalthorp did you ever find a satisfying answer to this question?  I am wondering essentially the same thing...

Comment: No, I think it's a very difficult question